# My best moment is every moment I've had with him/spent with him

Tags: word-usage

A person was asked: "What was your best moment with your dad?"

So the reply can be: "My best moment was every moment with him."

**But can it be**:
...

> 1.)My best moment was every moment that I had with my dad.
>
> 2.)My best moment was every moment that I spent with my dad.

What sounds natural #1 or #2? Do any of these sentences sound natural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear, it seems like your intention is to make this sentence *deliberately* paradoxical - obviously *one best* moment cannot be *every* moment. But this is fine and makes sense in context - it is like a frame challenge. The implication is that it is impossible to choose a single best moment so you are answering your own question in a  different way.

That out of the way, the most natural sounding (to me at least) of your two suggestions is #2:

> My best moment was every moment that *I spent* with my dad.

This is a personal preference, as there is nothing incorrect with your first sentence grammatically. My two reasons for preferring this are:

1. "Time spent with" someone carries stronger the idea that you mutually enjoyed the time together.
2. "Had" rhymes with "dad" which makes it a little jarring and possibly a little harder to say.

Comment: So will it be natural to use #1 as well? And what about the sentence "My favorite moment it every moment with dad" ?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Yes it is just a preference. Your new example, yes, if you use "is", not "it". This use of present tense suggests you still enjoy time with your dad, whereas the others sound like it was something in the past.

Comment: [grammar: So is it natural to use etc. "will" is wrong here.]

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.  "Spent" is probably more common, but "had" may be better, as a reply to a question that uses the same verb, e.g.:

> A: What was the best moment you **had** with your father?
>   B: My best moment was *every* moment that I **had** with my dad.

Beyond what is *correct* and *natural*, there is good English writing/speaking *style*.  As in any language, some people can do it well, and some can't.  There are good writers and bad writers, good speakers and bad speakers.  Some people can say something clever very quickly, "off the cuff", and some can only be clever when they have time to sit and write it down.

It's good style to mirror the general form of the question asked, but with a wry, humorous, or insightful twist.  Your first example is somewhat like this, where the questioner expects you to respond with one or perhaps a couple of anecdotes, but the response is unexpected but sweet.

Of course, the trick about being clever is that you have to be *original*.  This kind of twist ("every moment is the best") has been done so many times it's pretty much cliche.  It's also not a real answer to the question.  If you really want to sound clever, you might have to dig a little deeper:

> A: What's the best moment you had with your father?
>   B: The best moments are the ones I'd nearly forgotten about, until something passing -- a smell, a flash of color, a word -- sparks the memory, and I'm back reliving that moment with him, as if it was that very day.

Comment: Is it possble to use the past perfect here— _My best moment was every moment that I had had with my dad_ ?

Comment: @MvLog sure if you reference some subsequent point in time, *"... before he passed away."* But it's generally not needed.

Answer (score 1):

These are both idiomatic:

To spend a moment with someone
To have a moment with someone

So, either way is fine and both are natural.